# Send Post Data in Arabic Language using Volley Post request with multipart

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

First of all sorry for my bad English,Actually i'm stucked at one point. i want to send Arabic text in database. API already works when i send it with post man request. but when i send it with Volley request it not sending proper text it convert into some kinds of characters instead of actual string.

sample code for sending request

```
VolleyPostRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyPostRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
          response -> {

          },
          error -> {
          }) {
         @Override
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(AppConstants.API_DATA, data);
            params.put("key", POST_API_KEY);
            return params;
         }
      };
      volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
      AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
      AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(volleyMultipartRequest);
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(volleyMultipartRequest);
```

String which i pass to server "{\"error\":\"العنوان بالعربية\"}"

String which stored in database  'D9FH'F ('D91(J)

I'm passing direct string in getParams() in data.

i also tried with URL URLEncoder.encode(jsonError, "UTF-8") but it gives me 500 Error.

Comment: try Uri.encode("Arabictext"). I also faced this problem

Comment: If i am using Uri.encode("arabictext"). than also its showing encoded text as %D8%AB%D9%81%D9%81%D8%BA%D8%BA

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to set a content-type header:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

and/or set the content-type for the body's content:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}
```

setting the header should already suffice, in conjunction with `getParams()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable feedback , but i resolved it by using URL Encoder

sample code

```
private void encodeString(String input){
     try {
         return URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf-8");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the same problem, 
It is simple and it works:

1) Encode the String (In Post request):

```
private void encode_str(String str){
 try {
     return URLEncoder.encode(str, "utf-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

2) Decode again (After getting data from API):

```
private void encode_str(String str){
  try {
     return URLDecoder.decode(str, "utf-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Note:** 
after encoding, the data will looks like:

```
  %D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF+%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%F0%9F%98%8C
```

but after you decode it again it will return.

Thanks for John